# Div Printing! The printed data is not set in multiple pages for a long table having 300 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using the Div print method to download or print the data of a long table. i face the problem that only a few columns are shown on one page and the remaining is looking cutting on the first page...means the data is not setting in multiple pages,as shown in the below pictures...
The code that i'm using is below

$scope.pdf = function () {

```
    var getpanel = document.getElementById("table-scroll");
    var MainWindow = window.open('', '', '');
    var style = document.getElementById('printcss').value;
    MainWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    MainWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles/Print.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>");

    MainWindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print();window.close()">');
    MainWindow.document.write(getpanel.innerHTML + '<style>' + style + '</style>');
    MainWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    MainWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        MainWindow.print();
    }, 500)
    return false;
}
```

[image]

The scroller in the above picture shows too many data...
while the the data is printed like this... as shown in the below picture

[image]

Comment: read the table and recreate it to few tables that would fit your page width. I encountered similar question and this is the only solution that comes to my mind. Of course javascript

Comment: but it difficult to manage in different table. because i'm using too many AngularJs filters...